# Why is my Openstack Auth Module no longer working?

Tags: python, openstack-keystone, openstack-api

I have a project that authenticates against the keystone API using python, in the last few weeks my auth method has stopped working and I can't see why.

The module looks like this:

```py
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from keystoneauth1 import session as keystone_session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client
from keystoneclient import utils

def connect():
    auth = v3.Password(
        auth_url="http://localhost:5000/v3/",
        username="admin",
        password="secret",
        project_name="admin",
        user_domain_name="default",
        project_domain_name="default"
        )
    session = keystone_session.Session(auth=auth,verify=False)
    keystone = client.Client(session=session,interface="public")
    return (keystone)
```

When I run `keystone.projects.list()` in ipython using the above code I get an **unauthorized** error and I don't understand why. If I use the same credentials with the openstack cli client and run `openstack project list` I get the list of projects I expect.

Environment:

- python-openstackclient   4.0.0
- python-keystoneclient    3.19.0

I am certain I have missed something important.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code (`password=s"secret"`), but other than that, everything looks fine. If I replace `auth_url` and `password` with values appropriate for my local cloud, this works fine.

Comment: The typo is because I was replacing variables with text :-) I will fix the typo. 
Unfortunately this means that there is something in my local keystone that is not working properly or not being configured properly.

Comment: Anything interesting in your keystone log? How are you providing the credentials to the openstack client?

Comment: The keystone log just shows the same error message and nothing else. I use system environment variables for the client as per the docs. I will spin up the environment on the weekend to see if I can debug further. It just seems strange that the client is working but the code that does essentially the same fails.

Comment: So it seems this error only happens when I run my code against a keystone instance that I created in a container for running the tests. I am not sure why it is failing for now as it seems that user that I create as part of the setup is not able to see the default project.

I will have to try to figure that out. 
This is the repository for the docker image https://github.com/lhaig/usery-keystone